# Is it okay to store user data on GitHub Gist?

Tags: store, gist, user-data

I recently made a web app which saves the user's data on GitHub Gist to make it shareable. These Gists are quite large (depending on the user) and contain binary data (mp3 files).
Now even though Gist allows automated uploads through its API, I'm unsure if it's actually okay to abuse Gist in order to store users' data or is this actually intended?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to your question can probably be found here - https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't be sure where exactly to look.

Comment: At the end of the TOS page from the link above, there is this: https://github.com/contact . Worth checking it out first.